# How to use GitLab and Gitlab-Mattermost on one machine?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, mattermost

My conf-file:

```
external_url "http://192.168.3.23"  # note the use of a dotted ip

gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = 'gitlab@myhome.com'
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_display_name'] = 'gitlab'
#gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_reply_to'] = 'gitlab@myhome.com'

gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "mail.home"
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 25
gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "myhome.com"

mattermost_external_url 'http://192.168.3.23'
mattermost['gitlab_enable'] = true
mattermost['gitlab_secret'] = "4d1e<***>bdbfe"
mattermost['gitlab_id'] = "1c441<***>092df"
mattermost['gitlab_scope'] = ""
mattermost['gitlab_auth_endpoint'] = "http://192.168.3.23/oauth/authorize"
mattermost['gitlab_token_endpoint'] = "http://192.168.3.23/oauth/token"
mattermost['gitlab_user_api_endpoint'] = "http://192.168.3.23/api/v3/user"


# Shut down GitLab services on the Mattermost server
#gitlab_rails['enable'] = false
```

But now by the address `192.168.3.23` loading only gitlab.
`GitLab Community Edition 8.4.4 9c31cc6`!
How to start use gitlab and mattermost together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need use different url-address for GitLab and Mattermost.

```
extermanl_url "http://192.168.3.23"
...
mattermost_external_url "http://192.168.3.23:8065"
```

Solve [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/13530).

Comment: Have you used "http://192.168.3.23:8065" or only "http://192.168.3.23" URL, while creating  mattermost['gitlab_secret'] on gitlab application?

Comment: I have created `gitlab_secret` using the URL with the port number.After running `gitlab-ctl` service, it's showing mattermost service is running but it is not allocating the port which I have mentioned(8090 - nothing is running on port 8090) and the mattermost URL is not reachable as well.What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I cam to know about my foolish act.After making changes to the `gitlab.rb` I forgot to run 'gitlab-ctl reconfigure'.

Comment: It seems using port 8065 isn't a good idea as it conflicts with nginx default port (see [this](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/1872#note_29156814)). Use any other port.